# getRotate or angel from MoveModifier in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I have set the Move Modifier in a random way.

```
MoveModifier mod1=new MoveModifier(5,0,rand_X,now_Y,rand_Y);
```

I have tried the Pythagorean formula,

```
float a = mod1.getToValueA();
float b = mod1.getToValueB();
float c = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a,2)+Math.pow(b,2));
float rotate = (float) (Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(a/c)));
```

and i try

```
mySprite.setRotation(rotate);
```

its angle is not heading towards a goal mySprite MoveModifier.
is there any other way to take the angle of MoveModifier?

Comment: so you want to turn your sprite towards the movement / end point of movemodifier? I have some code for you at home, will post it later :) (now only laptop) Stand by :)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to set rotation for your sprite before or after MoveModifier movements. because during movement through MoveModifier you cant change sprite status until you clear entity modifiers.